# Byte array (Web Api 2) to blob (Angular client)

Tags: c#, .net, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I want to download a file from Web Api, using Angular as a client side. My file is unfortunately broken when I downloading it at my browser. I think it is a fault of type discrepancy.

> Web Api controller returns "byte[]"

Angular service:

```
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob });
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/MyAction', ac, options)
        .map(res => res.blob())
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

Angular component ts

```
  this.service.downloadXls(items).subscribe(
            data => this.downloadFile(data)),
             error => console.log("Error downloading the file."),
             () => console.info("OK");
  }
  downloadFile(data: Blob) {
    let blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' });
    let url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);
  }
```

As I understand I need to receive byte[] and convert it to blob on the client side. Or convert and send blob on the server side. I don't know how to do either.

Comment: Why is this marked as duplicate? To OP: You need to use this: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Comment: Had problems with File saver. The method I used works fine. Problem is that my file is broken

Comment: The method you use only 'seems' to work. The problem is it isn't decoding it correctly, that's why you get a broken file.

Comment: Post another question detailing the problem you are having with FileSaver, I will try to help.

Comment: I'm only speaking from a Java standpoint more than anything else, but I'm not fully convinced that this question is a dupe.  What is the MIME type that you want to send across?

Comment: Excel file, build via EPPlus.

Comment: I seem to be missing the c# part. If you say it returns "byte[]" do you meant the type it returns is `byte[]` or that the payload that comes over the wire is `System.Byte[]`. And I mean that literally.

Comment: I create ExcelPackage, fill it with data and returning it by xlPackage.GetAsByteArray(); (as a test I created a file on disk from this array, and it was valid excel file)

Answer (score 2):

Fetching a binary stream is not that straightforward, I suggest you use [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) to do the heavy lifting.

I don't have Angular experience, but here is a code snippet I used on a project not too long ago. It is plain JavaScript but should be reusable on Angular with minor modification:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="FileSaver.min.js"></script>
  <script>        
    function download() {            
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "http://your.url", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/octet-stream");
        //xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ......");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: "octet/stream"});
                var fileName = "my_excel_file.xlsx";
                saveAs(blob, fileName);
            }
        }
        xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
        xhr.send();
    }        
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="javascript:download()">Download Excel File</button>
</body>
</html>
```